# Не запускается Apache

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2

После установки apache выдает ошибку:

> symbol lookup error: /usr/sbin/apache2: undefined symbol: apr-os-uuid-get

OS: Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: aptitude purge apache2 && aptitude install apache2

Comment: Пробовал не помогает.

Comment: Может у вас что осталось от установки. Попробуйте удалить и после поискать по locate *httpd* и locate *apache*. Перед этим выполните updatedb.

Comment: пакет libapr1 переставьте.

Answer (score 2):

ответ из комментария:

пакет libapr1 переставьте